# How can I remove cookies stored by WebView in Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, cookies, webkit

My Cocoa app uses `WebView` to open pages that uses cookies. For testing purposes I want to remove those cookies. How can I do this (programmatically or manually) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, cookies were shared between apps on Mac OS X. So you could use the Safari preferences to remove all cookies.

However, as of OS X 10.11, that potential security hole has been closed, and all apps have their own cookie store. (and even before that, sandboxed apps had their own cookie store too)

Comment: Any way to prevent sharing of such cookies?

Comment: The only ways are to sandbox your app, or customise every URL request not to perform http cookie handling

Comment: @MikeAbdullah how do you customise URL request to do your own cookie handling?

Comment: The `WebResourceLoadDelegate` gives you a chance to modify outgoing requests. `mutableCopy` will give you a mutable one where you can tell WebKit not to do supply cookies for you. Similar API is available for handling responses. I've lost track though, better API might be available for cookie handling these days

Comment: @MikeAbdullah Is it possible to access the shared cookies in a sandbox app?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not possible

Comment: FYI:
According to the NSHTTPCookieStorage documentation:
Starting in OS X 10.11, each app has its own sharedHTTPCookieStorage singleton, which will not be shared with other applications.

Comment: Very true Ken; updating my answer

Answer (score 6):

If you wanted to do it programmatically, you can use [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You'll need `cookiesForURL:` and `deleteCookie:`. Something a little like this (untested):

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [cookieJar cookiesForURL:@"http://myserver.com"]) 
{
  [cookieJar deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Comment: messing with the shared cookies from some random app seems like a security leak to me. I assume that the cookie jar is just a clone of the original and that you are actually deleting the cookies only for the current session? As in... they are back the next time you run the app?