# How do I clear saved cookies of wxWEBVIEW_WEBKIT used in an app on macOS?

Tags: macos, webview, webkit, wxwidgets

I'm working on a cross-platform wxWidgets-based application that uses a WebView for a web-based OAuth login to a web site. The web site's OAuth login process uses cookies to cache a login token once authenticated, so that you can go through the process again to get another OAuth token if necessary without the user having to enter their credentials again. The WebView backend implementation `wxWEBVIEW_WEBKIT` that I'm using in the macOS version of the app preserves cookies between restarts of my app and even reboots of the OS.  This makes it difficult to test the login process.

Where is the WebView backend persisting these cookies?  How would I go about clearing them?

I've already tried clearing the cookies in Safari to no avail, and I removed all of the obvious cache files I saw in the app's file accesses as captured by `opensnoop`, but the cached login is still present.

Comment: you will have better luck asking on the wx-users ML, where Steve L. is (the author of this piece).

Comment: Did you try Keychain? http://www.macworld.com/article/2013756/how-to-manage-passwords-with-keychain-access.html

Comment: I did notice access to the keychain files in the `opensnoop` output, so I took a look in Keychain Access, and went through All Items in all the Categories, but I didn't see anything that was obviously a cookie or other browser saved info. However I don't really know what I'm looking for exactly.

Comment: @Igor Thanks, I'll give that a try also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [a response on the wx-users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/5RTuaCHjnW0), `wxWEBVIEW_WEBKIT` is implemented using a simple macOS [`WebView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/webview).

As noted in [How can I remove cookies stored by WebView in Cocoa application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081247/how-can-i-remove-cookies-stored-by-webview-in-cocoa-application), in macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) and later, each application's WebViews have their own cookie storage and do not have access to each others' cookies.

I did not find a way to manually clear my application's cookies; I tried removing the relevant `*.binarycookies` file from `~/Library/Cookies` but that had no effect. It's still unclear to me where the cookies are stored.

However I was able to delete the cookies programmatically using the [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage) API, following the code snippet in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486398/60422. I ended up just adding a menu item for this to my application to clear the cookies that I only use for manual testing purposes.